# Cannot access @model in a Razor view located on a folder outside the "~/Views/..."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In the VS2017 project, I had to create a view outside the  "~/Views/..." folder and I added the "@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage" . It works but after I added a model, it says "The name model does not exist in the current context. Bellow is the view code. My question is if there is a solution or do I have to move it back to the default folder, which will be another problem, since it is a client's specific view and there are several different clients.

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage

@model (underline in red)
```

Comment: Are you using the full namespace of the model or just the typename?

Comment: check the namespaces in your web.config of your views directory.

Comment: I cannot write anything after @model

Comment: Certainly you need web.config file which includes `system.web.webPages.razor` element with similar content like used in `Views` folder in place where you're adding CSHTML file outside `Views` folder.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto The solution worked. If placed as an answer it will be accepted